# import package Bean for annotation in java

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I use the @Bean annotation in java with spring-boot and I can not find the module I need to import.

```
@SpringBootApplication 
public class Application {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
 }

 @Bean
 public PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor persistenceBeanPostProcessor() {
     return new PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor();
 } 
}
```

Comment: It should in package `org.springframework.context.annotation`

Comment: Should be also in the package spring-boot-starter-data-jpa from your pom